# log42j and syslog-ng output format

Tags: log4j2, syslog-ng

my syslog-ng config is:

```
source s_src { tcp(ip(127.0.0.1) port(1000)); };
destination df_local0 { file ("/var/log/mylog-${YEAR}.${MONTH}.${DAY}.log" template("${YEAR}${MONTH}${DAY}-${HOUR}${MIN}${SEC} ${MESSAGE}\n")); };
filter f_local0 { facility(local0);};
log { source(s_src); filter(f_local0); destination(df_local0);};
```

my log4j2.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn" name="MyAppx" packages="">
<Appenders>
    <Syslog name="RFC5424" format="RFC5424" host="127.0.0.1" port="1000"
            protocol="TCP" appName="app" mdcId="mdc" includeMDC="true"
            facility="LOCAL0" enterpriseNumber="" newLine="true" immediateFail="false"
            messageId="" id="" ignoreExceptions="true">
    <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HHmmss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
     <LoggerFields>
        <KeyValuePair key="level" value="%level"/>
        <KeyValuePair key="location" value="%location"/>
        <KeyValuePair key="ex" value="%ex"/>
         </LoggerFields>
</Syslog>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Root level="debug">
        <AppenderRef ref="RFC5424" />
    </Root>
</Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

my output syslog-ng output is:

```
20150518-151925 2015-05-18T15:19:25.546+02:00 node001-NT-A2400-NT-A3500 app -  [mdc@18060 ex="" level="DEBUG" location="eu.test.prot.ads.ADSClient.run(ADSClient.java:431)"] Thread top
```

as you can see, there is per default an timestamp in this format

```
2015-05-18T15:19:25.546+02:00
```

also the hostname is printed. How can I influence the output?

Is there also an oportunity to access the log4j LoggerFields in syslog-ng.conf?

I would like to have an output like

```
20150518-151925 - app - DEBUG - eu.test.prot.ads.ADSClient.run(ADSClient.java:431)" - Thread top
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess that syslog-ng does not recognize the timestamp in the log4j message, and appends the timestamp.

Also, in your syslog-ng configuration you use the tcp() source, which is mainly used for receiving RFC3164 messages, but in log4j you set format="RFC5424".
Try to change your syslog-ng config to use the syslog() source: https://www.balabit.com/sites/default/files/documents/syslog-ng-ose-latest-guides/en/syslog-ng-ose-guide-admin/html/configuring-sources-syslog.html

HTH
Regards,

Robert Fekete